MikroTik console command gets stuck
I am observing frequent yet not 100% repeatable cases where a console command aimed at removing all items from a given list (remove [find] to be exact) gets stuck while executing. The following is true:

Happens to different collections of items, e.g. /ip/dhcp-server remove [find], /interface/bridge remove [find] and so on.
Happens both when the target collection of items is non-empty and empty.
Happens both in the script as well as a standalone call in the terminal window, but seems like it happens more often when running from a script.
Happens in about 20% of calls.
Sometimes takes very long time to complete, but still finishes, sometimes takes forever to complete, sometimes takes long time and then exits with timeout message.
RouterOS 7.14.3 (most current stable version)

Hence the questions:

Why such a trivial call would get stuck, especially in non-deterministic manner?
Is there another way to remove all items from a given collection that would not cause the execution to get stuck?

